# Unix: finding a string within a directory and listing only its associated file names

Tags: string, unix

I have been working on this for quite some time and decided to ask for some help. I'm trying to use a command to find a multiple occurrences of a function (basically a string) within a directory (that has multiple files) and would like to view only the file names which the string is found.

Lets say this was the directory I want to search filled with multiple .h and .cpp files is: 
~/Project/Files

and I was looking for occurrences of a function called 'doThis'

So far I have tried:

```
grep -r doThis ~/Project/Files
```

But I get the path and where it occurs in the file, I only need the file names.

Also grep -f wont work because I get an error message saying "No such file or directory" and when using just grep I get an error message saying "path is a directory"

Any help would be great: Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the `-l` switch ;)
So :

```
grep -rl foobar dir
```